# Perl :Out of Memory Error while building a 2d array at run time

Tags: perl, out-of-memory, binaryfiles, dynamic-arrays, perl-data-structures

I am perl beginner. I am trying to build a 2d array at run time from a binary file. I am getting a "out of memory" error. I am using Perl 5.16.3 in windows7. My input file size is ~4.2MB. My system has a physical memory of 4GB and I am hitting 90% usage and then showing up the out of memory error when I run this code.

I tried lot of ways to debug this. Only If I reduce the b32 to b16 or less, I am able to run successfully. Even with this, if the file size increase beyond 4MB, the error shows up again. I tried looking at physical memory usage in task manager while executing the code, it keep on increasing.

My friend suspected this should be memory leak issue. I couldnt make out with his suspect.
I need help on fixing this.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

open( DATA, 'debug.bin' ) or die "Unable to open:$!";
binmode DATA;
my ( $data, $n, $i );
my @2dmatrix;
while ( $n = read DATA, $data, 4 ) {
    push @2dmatrix, [ split( '', unpack( 'b32', $data ) ) ];
}
print scalar(@2dmatrix);
print "completed reading";
close(DATA);
```

Just to clear the requirement. From the 2d array build, I need to extract contents from a column A  corresponding to a particular pattern (11111111000000001111111100000000) in column B. This needs to be done on 4 set of columns with a file size of 500Mb.

Comment: Try to chunk the data into smaller size of blocks which may help you in resolving out of memory error.

Comment: the English requirements are a whole lot more ambiguous than code would be; do you only need 40 rows at a time?

Comment: @ysth Yes. but which 40 rows cannot be decided directly. I have to ignore lot of rows in between, depending on the use case.So, I chose the build the whole array and process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a memory leak, your program is just very inefficient with memory use.

For every 4 bytes you read in, you do an `unpack 'b32'` which creates a 32-character string; `split //` it, which turns it into 32 1-character strings, make an arrayref of the resulting list, and push the arrayref on `@2dmatrix`. That results in:

- 32 string bodies, each at least 2 bytes (for `"0\0"` or `"1\0"`) although perl might decide to use more to avoid reallocations if the strings grow: 64 bytes.
- 32 SVPVs (scalar variables containing strings, 28 bytes each on 32-bit, 40 bytes each on 64-bit): 896 or 1280 bytes.
- 1 array body with 32 entries: 128 bytes on 32-bit, 256 bytes on 64-bit.
- 1 AV (array variable): 28 bytes on 32-bit, 40 bytes on 64-bit.
- 1 SVRV (scalar containing a reference): 16 bytes on 32-bit, 24 bytes on 64-bit.
- 1 entry in `@2dmatrix`'s array body: 4 bytes on 32-bit, 8 bytes on 64-bit.

With a result of 1136 bytes per 4 bytes (284x multiplication) on 32-bit and 1672 bytes per 4 bytes (418x multiplication) on 64-bit, not accounting for constant factors and the fact that perl might choose to use larger string bodies (on two versions of perl I tested here, I got either 10 or 16 bytes, not 2.) As such your program will use upwards of 1.1GB of memory for a 4.2MB input on a 32-bit system, and upwards of 1.7GB of memory for a 4.2MB input on a 64-bit system.

The solution here is to store and access the data in a more efficient way, but I can't give any specific advice because you haven't said what you're actually trying to *do* with `@2dmatrix` once you have it.

Comment: storing numbers instead of strings is an easily gained efficiency (`[ map $_?1:0, split...]` instead of `[split...]`), saving 576 bytes on 64-bit perl.

Comment: @ysth yeah, I would actually suggest storing 32-bit numbers and using a combination of array indexing and bitshifting to access members as a decent compromise between space and convenience (gets you down to a ~1 million entry array with no indirection), but anything from `vec` to not actually reading the file in at all could work, which is why I'd like to hear more requirements :)

Comment: if they are going to make code changes in whatever is actually using the array of arrays, just reading the whole file into a string and using vec is probably easiest

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. I wanted to save the data as binary matrix. @ysth: I will try your idea.

Comment: @tirumalesh please do show how you are *using* the data as hobbs requested; that will help us give you better advice

Comment: @ysth already updated the question with details on how I want to use the data. let me know if you need any other detials.

Comment: @hobbs I want to process the 2d matrix column wise. So, stroing as 32-bit numbers will not help me. I dont know about vec. trying to understand this online.

Answer (score 1):

Forget reading in memory whole file content. Make function to access to data(x,y) which subsequently will access value in file Also consider looking at http://search.cpan.org/~leont/File-Map-0.63/lib/File/Map.pm#Advantages_of_memory_mapping

Comment: 4MB of data can fit in memory just fine without memory mapping the file. The problem is that the OP's current approach is extremely inefficient.

Comment: Sorry Misunderstanding. I thought of 4Gb file.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the whole file into a string and using vec looks like this:

```
my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };
```

Then to get a particular row/col, use:

```
$value = vec( $data, $row*32+$col, 1 );
```

Comment: I am trying to understand your example,$value above reads an [$row,$col] element in 2d array. Can I read a row/col array from vec?

Comment: use `vec($data, $row*32+$col, 1)` instead of `$twodarray[$row][$col]`; is that clearer?